# How to install the new version of Redactor Imperavi?

Tags: yii2, redactor

I have this one

```
Redactor v10.0.9
```

I try this

```
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget": "1.2.2
```

But i always get the same version v10.0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade to the latest version of the widget, which at the time of writing is [1.2.10](https://github.com/vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget/releases).

Just put `"vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget": "^1.2.10"` into your `composer.json` file. Putting the [caret symbol before the version](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret) ensures that future non-breaking updates will be loaded automatically when you run `composer update`.